# Plot values with a filter - Matplotlib does not support generators as input

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a df with values from 0 to 20000. I want to apply a filter so I can only plot those values below 3000. Here is how I tried it.

```
def f(x):
  if x > 3000:
    return False
  else:
    return True

y_3000 = filter(f, y1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows =2, ncols=1)

ax.set_title('Cell 13', fontsize= 18)
ax.plot(x1, y_3000, label = 'Values', color = 'green')   
plt.show()
```

While doing this I happen to encounter this message: "matplotlib does not support generators as input".

How can I make a filter to only plot the lower values that I want?

Comment: Try this `y_3000=list(filter(f,y1))`.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message, because that is not a matplotlib error message.  You also should specify what `filter` is.  (i.e. please include your library imports in your example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [plotting-data-from-generator-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768357/plotting-data-from-generator-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can easily be done with `numpy`. You just need convert your `x, y` values to numpy array, and then do filtering by `y[y < 3000]` for `y` and `x[y <= 3000]` for `x`. Here is minimal example how to plot values `y <= 50`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(0, 100)
y = np.arange(0, 100)

plt.plot(x[y <= 50], y[y <= 50])
```

[image: img]